# Order 5 rational map?

Tags: functions

$p(z) = 1-\frac{1}{z}$ has order 3: $p(p(p(z))) = z$

Is there an order 5 rational map with rational coefficients?

Comment: Are there rational maps of order 4? (Order 2 is easy: $1/z$)

Comment: @lhf $z\mapsto\frac{z+1}{-z+1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a rational map would be a linear fractional transformation:
$$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}.$$
Its $k$-th iterate is the identity iff $A^k=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda$
where $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$. If the coefficients $a,\ldots,d$ are rational
this is impossible for $k=5$ unless $f$ is already the identity. The eigenvalues of
$A$ would have to be $\sqrt[5]{\lambda}\zeta$ and $\sqrt[5]{\lambda}\zeta^{-1}$
for some non-trivial fifth root of unity $\zeta$. Their sum and product must be
rational, so that $\lambda^{2/5}\in\Bbb Q$ which means that $\sqrt[5]{\lambda}$
is rational. But then $\sqrt[5]{\lambda}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$ is irrational, a contradiction.

Comment: Why is the first sentence true?

Comment: @lhf You need $f$ to be injective....